# PHP Include file not seeing variables set before being included

Tags: php, variables, pdo, include

I have a main.php file.

In this file, I include my PDO/DB connection, like so:

Content of PDO include file:

```
$dbhost = 'blah';
$dbname = 'blah';
$dbuser = 'blah'; //Read/Write
$dbpass = 'blah';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

included in the main file like so: (I also declare the table name after it)

```
include '../_include/path_to_pdo.php';
$tablename = 'some_table_name';
```

I have another file I am including that is basically just a file full of functions to keep the main file more readable, and not have all the database stuff in there and only use the predetermined functions.

```
include 'external_functions.php';
```

In this external_functions.php file.. are a group of functions that will return/output data (or markup..whatever) in the MAIN.php file when executed.

These functions make database calls...etc..

However, these functions in the external_functions.php file are NOT seeing the:

```
$tablename
$conn
```

vars there were declared in the MAIN.php file.. or in the PDO connection/setup...

In the external_functions.php file.. if I echo out:

```
$tablename
```

It displays fine..

but not when used inside the function... nor the $conn database handle var declared in the PDO include file.

I have even tried to pass in the $tablename as an argument to the function..

example of the function:

```
function get_someList($tablename){ //doesnt work, var not seen
    //get some list
    $someDetails_sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename ORDER BY category"; //doesnt work
    $someDetails_stmt = $conn->prepare($someDetails_sql);
    $someDetails_stmt->execute();
    $someDetails_stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_someList = $someDetails_stmt->fetchAll(); //returns multi-dimensional array (and correct count)

    //do whatever

}
```

How can I fix this?  and what am I doing wrong? If outside the function, $tablename echo's fine... inside the function its lost?  (even when attempting to pas it in as an argument?   Why???

Also, how would I go about passing in the $conn var to the function as well, so that it too can be used in the query/prepare statement??

Comment: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: You will have to pass the connection to the function or the function will never see it because it is not global.

Comment: Wow... look at the time difference between my comment above and the close. I'd call this the closeness award of the day.

Comment: @deceze  if its a duplicate, then post the link to the former question. (otherwise its not very helpful)

I have tried to pass $conn as an argument, but it didnt work..  (I was hoping NOT to use globals,.. but doing so worked so far for the $tablename var.

Comment: Uhm, yeah… look at the top of your question.

Comment: @deceze

Ahh thank you, I was not aware it would be posted there.

Although I didnt want to, I opt'd to use globals. :(   (its working, but I feel scummy!)  haha

I'm still not clear on another way if passing them as arguments to the function do not work?